# MS SQL Update one table from another table with multiple masterid and different childid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a best approach to update 1 table from another table which has common multiple id's.

Below is the Scenario

Table1:

```
+----------+---------+
| masterid | childid |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | NULL    |
+----------+---------+
```

Table2:

```
+----------+---------+
| masterid | childid |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 4       |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | 9       |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | 8       |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 5       |
+----------+---------+
```

I wish to update `table1` comparing the `masterid` of `table2` and corresponding `childid` should be be updated.

Solution1: Using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;
WITH cte
AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
FROM @t1),
cte1
AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
FROM @t2)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.childid = t2.childid
FROM cte AS t1
INNER JOIN cte1 AS t2
  ON t2.masterid = t1.masterid
  AND t2.rn = t1.rn
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/YSD84308)

How this can be achieved in different ways?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have? Why are you looking for a different answer?

Comment: Your method is fine unless you have already one sequences.

Comment: Are you looking for a different way?

Comment: Can this be achieved in a different way. Just for learning purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @TAble1 AS TABLE (masterid INT , childid INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 1 , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , NULL UNION ALL   
SELECT 2 , NULL UNION ALL   
SELECT 2 , NULL UNION ALL   
SELECT 1 , NULL    

DECLARE @TAble2 AS TABLE (masterid INT , childid INT)
INSERT INTO @TAble2
SELECT  1, 2UNION ALL      
SELECT  1, 3UNION ALL      
SELECT  1, 4UNION ALL      
SELECT  2, 9UNION ALL      
SELECT  2, 8UNION ALL      
SELECT  1, 5
```

This Update State is enough to update table Table1 No Need to use Any window function

```
SELECT * FROM @TAble1

UPDATE T1
SET T1.childid = T2.childid
FROM @TAble1 T1
INNER JOIN @TAble2 T2
ON T1.masterid = T2.masterid

SELECT * FROM @TAble1
```

Result Before Update

```
masterid    childid
1           NULL
1           NULL
1           NULL
2           NULL
2           NULL
1           NULL
```

Result After Update

```
masterid    childid
1            2
1            2
1            2
2            9
2            9
1            2
```

Comment: The update will match the first record and update accordingly. What i am expecting is to get all consecutive child record also to be updated. The result should be same as Table2 after update. How this could have been achieved before MS SQL 2008 as ROW_NUMBER was introduce after 2008.